# spring kafka looking for the latest available message in a topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer which subscribes to the following topics `MY_TOPIC`, `MY_UNINTERESTED_TOPIC`.

In the following scenario I am not interested in the second topic but I had to mention it because if I configure it using something like `auto.offset.reset` it may affect all the topics.

On `MY_TOPIC` topic I publish different kind of messages: `MESSAGE_TYPE_A` and `MESSAGE_TYPE_B`. Both messages are instances of `BaseKafkaMessage` (custom class) with different properties.

Now I am interested in finding **only** the **latest** message of type MESSAGE_TYPE_A. How can I do that?

The real scenario is this one: I publish two types of messages on the same topic. One of them is used to prepare a local cache in each consumer that is interested in this topic and that message. If a consumer stops, when it reloads it must reinitialize its cache with the latest `MESSAGE_TYPE_A`. `MESSAGE_TYPE_B` should be ignored. I don't want to send a notification on Kafka to the data provider to publish the data again because all the subscribers will have a lot of unnecessary work to do.

How can I obtain this? Is this possible?

I found https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#seek but I am not sure if it is what I am looking for or if there is another way to do it.

Comment: but whenever consumer restarts, it will pull the new data right? then why do worry about `MESSAGE_TYPE_B`, and this property `auto.offset.reset` will be affected if it is new consumer group

Comment: @Deadpool please take a look at the answer provided by cricket_007 and also my comment

Comment: Do you have any idea about consumer group id? I really don't understand how consumer will poll from begining when it just restarts with sama group id? @tzortzik

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what format these messages are in or why you really need them to be in the same topic at all.

You could [use different Avro types](https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/) for example. Or you would have to `try-catch` parsing two different byte arrays (JSON objects?)

Or you could partition your topic by type such that all messages of one type are in-order of the same partition.

But, there is no mechanism to do index-lookups to get the most-recently sent message. Either you start from the latest event, and you get the next incoming message, or you can start from the beginning, then scan up until you get 0 records on the next poll loop, which in-theory is the "most-recent"

> something like auto.offset.reset it may affect all the topics

That only affects those topics for which the consumer is interested it, not all.

Comment: Avro is not a solution for me at this point. I do not want to use `auto.offset.reset` because my consumer subscribes to topics like `ORDER_MANAGEMENT` and `PRODUCT_MANAGEMENT`. In this case we may recreate an order or product that has been previously created. I'm only interested in `PRODUCT_MANAGEMENT` with messages of type (type is a field on the message) ` PRODUCT_CACHE_UPDATE`. The solution you propose is to search from the beginning until I have no messages and look for my latest `PRODUCT_CACHE_UPDATE`?

Comment: de-deuplicating records depends on your consumer logic. Changing a kafka property or not won't prevent it from happening. You could use Kafka Streams to `filter` out your one topic into 2 topics based on the types. Again, though, the act of "looking" requires a topic scan